# Elasticsearch Aggregation: Sum of latest childrens per parent

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-5

Having a parent-children structure in Elasticsearch representing an `order` with `order_revision` children I want to generate a histogram of the `price` showing the sum of the `quantity`.

```
{
  "_type": "order",
  "_id": "1063220887",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "order_id": "1063220887",
    "product_id": "10446350",
    "timestamp": 1462713302000
  }
}

{
  "_type": "order_revision",
  "_id": "10234234",
  "_parent": "1063220887",
  "_source": {
    "price": 9,
    "quantity": 3,
    "revision": 361,
    "timestamp": 1462712196000
  }
}
```

The following aggregation basically works but returns the sum of all exisiting revisions.

```
  {
    "aggs": {
      "orders": {
        "filter": {
          "has_parent": {
            "parent_type": "order"
          }
        },
        "aggs": {
          "quantity_per_price": {
            "histogram": {
              "field": "price",
              "interval": 1
            }
            "aggs": {
              "sum": {"field": quantity"}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

In the final version it should only return the sum of the `quantity` fields for the *latest* revision (with the highest/newest `timestamp`) of every order.
I'm not entirely sure how to come up with such an aggregation that does grouping by `order_id` and only selects the latest child, neither I'm sure if this parent-child structure is the best to model this data.

Comment: How many revisions do you have approximately per order? Are we talking in the magnitude of 1-2 or more like 10-20+?

Comment: It would be around 10....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest implementation would be to have the latest revision tagged (`"latest": true`) in the document. Then it becomes a simple issue of adding a query or a `filter` aggregation to filter only the latest revisions.

Comment: Note, though, that when a new revision comes in, you also need to remember to update the previous latest revision to `"latest": false`.

Comment: Thanks for your reploy... Didnt mention in the question that marking the latest is not a real option as furthermore I will also need to extend this functionality to also be able to step back in time... But as I dont think this is really possible with ES, so I'd accept your answer if nothing else comes in...